# Parsing a JSON Object Within a JSON Object in QT

Tags: c++, json, qt

I'm using QT5 to try and parse this JSON file.

### The Format

```
{
  "HwDescription": {
    "ConnectionsName": "file://settings/connections_2CBC.xml",
    "ShelveId": "0",
    "BeBoard": {
      "Id": "0",
      "connectionId": "board0",
      "boardType": "GLIB"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are objects within "HwDescription". I can't figure out how to extract them though. I can do 1D fine.

### My Attempt

Firstly I create the object:

```
QJsonParseError json_parse_error;
QJsonDocument json_doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawJson.toUtf8(), &json_parse_error);
QJsonObject json_result= json_doc.object();
return std::make_pair(json_result, json_parse_error);
```

This returns me my `json_result` as a QJsonObject - don't worry about this - this part definitely works.

Using my debugger, I can see the raw json has indeed been passed over correctly. So a

```
auto json_obj = json_result.first; //my breakpoint shows me that the data made it this far
//auto connection = json_obj.toObject(); //says there is no member named toObject in QObject

//none of the below methods work

auto test = json_obj["HwDescription","ConnectionsName"].toString();
QJsonArray cmd_array= json_obj["HwDescription"].toArray();
QStringList cmd_list;
for (auto item: cmd_array)
{
    cmd_list.append(item.toString());
}
m_modelCommands.setStringList(cmd_list);

//m_connectionsName = json_obj["HwDescription"].toString(); //this doesn't work either
```

I know it's the way I'm parsing is incorrect, can someone quickly show me where I'm going wrong? Then I'll be able to do it for my 3D objects also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
auto json_obj = json_result.first;

QJsonObject obj_HwDescription = json_obj["HwDescription"].toObject();
QString str_ConnectionsName = obj_HwDescription["ConnectionsName"].toString();
// ...
QJsonObject obj_BeBoard = obj_HwDescription["BeBoard"].toObject();
// ...
```

*Documentation*:

- [QJsonObject Class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonobject.html)
- [QJsonValue Class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you read about JSON, http://json.org/.

Anyway, a JSON object can be thought of as `std::map< std::string, anything >`, and that anything can be other JSON objects.

`json_obj["HwDescription"]` returns a json object, so in order to access ConnectionsName, you need `json_obj["HwDescription"][ConnectionsName]`.

`json_obj["HwDescription"]` does not return an array.  An example of an array is:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name":"fiz"
    },
    {
      "name":"carl"
    }
  ]
}
```

With that, you can write something like:

```
json_obj["people"].toArray()[0]["name"] == "fiz"; // true
```